# Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

Tags: mysql

For some reason I cannot create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_role (
  user_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
    REFERENCES roles(role_id)
);
```

The following similar table has no problems:

```
CREATE TABLE role_perm (
  role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  perm_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
    REFERENCES roles(role_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (perm_id)
    REFERENCES permissions(perm_id)
);
```

The error message I'm getting is:

`#1005 - Can't create table 'test.user_role' (errno: 150) (Details...)
Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must have the correct column names and types, and it must have indexes on the referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL returns Error 1005 and refers to Error 150 in the error message, which means that a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.

If is rather difficult to *guess* as you didn't provide the definitions for the `roles` and `permissions` tables but to paraphrase the doc...

- ...in order to have a foreign key on a column, you *must* have an index on the "target" column.
- ...in order to have a foreign key on a column, both "source" and "target" columns *must* have the same type (incl. the same size if applicable).
- ...in order to have a foreign key on a column, both tables *must* use InnoDB engine.

Comment: Thank you, I was using mis-matched types.

Comment: Had to read this to see i was setting not null on a column supposed to be nullable, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I handle several databases, when I try to create the table it returned this error "transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys", the error occurred because the relationship table did not exist,
casually it recognized it from another database where the table did exist, but i have only creating the relationship table to solve the problem.
I took into account the recommendations of relations given in this forum because it also has to do with the version of MySql.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).