# Creating a MySQL Table but get error

Tags: mysql, sql

I get

```
errnno 150: InnoDB Documentation

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
```

Here is the SQL:

```
-- Table structure for table `Serving_Info`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Serving_Info` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Food_Value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Served_On` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Oncall` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  Foreign key(`Oncall`) REFERENCES `employees`(`name`),
  Foreign key(`Food_name`) REFERENCES `Foods`(`Food_name`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Oncall`,`Food_name`, `Served_On`)
);
```

Any idea what is causing the error? I have tried making id part of the primary key but that isn't solving the problem either.

Here are the statements for the tables I am referencing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `confirmcode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
);
--
-- Table structure for table `Foods`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Foods` (
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `CostPerRefill` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Food_name`)
);
```

I just tried the below but I get the same error:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Serving_Info`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Serving_Info` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Food_Value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Served_On` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Oncall` varchar(128),
  Foreign key(`Oncall`) REFERENCES `employees`(`name`),
  Foreign key(`Food_name`) REFERENCES `Foods`(`Food_name`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`Oncall`,`Food_name`, `Served_On`)
);
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238321/supports-transactions-row-level-locking-and-foreign-keys

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the referenced columns? That could also be the issue.

Comment: As a note:  normally with this type of table `id` would be the primary key and the triple of columns would be declared `unique` (or have a unique index built on them).

Comment: You should post your CREATE TABLE statements for `Foods` and `employees` too, because you're referencing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the reference is to `employees.name` rather than `employees.id_user`.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Serving_Info` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Food_Value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Served_On` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Oncall` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  Foreign key(`Oncall`) REFERENCES `employees`(`id_user`),
  Foreign key(`Food_name`) REFERENCES `Foods`(`Food_name`),
  UNIQUE (`Oncall`,`Food_name`, `Served_On`)
);
```

Otherwise, change the `employees` table so `name` has an index:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL ,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `confirmcode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  KEY (name)
);
```

In practice, if you are going to use `name` this way, you should probably make that `unique` rather than just `key`.

Comment: my id_user is the username of the employee. It is not an ID number of an employee.

Comment: It worked  after I made name a key and then used the Unique on the 3 columns. I am still confused as to what the problem was about me keeping 3 columns as primary key.

Comment: @TomDerod . . . There is no "problem" with having a composite primary key.  You just have an auto-incremented id that will work better.  Consider a foreign key reference:  would you rather have to include all three keys in another table or simply the auto-incremented id?