# Adding multiple foreign key gives an error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to add multiple foreign key on a table 'routes1' but it still giving me an error `Cannot add foreign key constraint`, Am I missing some code?
Thanks in advance. 
here is the code snippet

```
CREATE TABLE `routes1` (
  `Airline` varchar(3) default NULL,
  `Airline_ID` int(11) default NULL,
  `Source_Airport` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `Source_Airport_ID` varchar(5) default NULL,
  `Destination_Airport` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `Destination_Airport_ID` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `CodeShare` char(1),
  `Stops` int(1),
  `Equipment` text,
 FOREIGN KEY(Airline_ID) REFERENCES airlines(Airline_ID)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(Source_Airport_ID) REFERENCES airports(Airport_ID)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

Here is the create table script for "airport" referencing table

```
CREATE TABLE `airports` (
  `Airport_ID` int(5),
  `Name` text,
  `City` text,
  `Country` text,
  `IATA/FAA`text default NULL,
 `ICAO` text,
  `Latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `Altitude` double NOT NULL,
  `Timezone` double not null,
 `dst` char(1) default NULL,
 `Tz_Database_time_zone` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Airport_ID`)
  );
```

Comment: The data type for Airport_ID is INT(5)

Comment: Data types must match plus some other conditions. Also post `create` scripts on tables that all involve in `foreign key` referencing.

Comment: posted create table script  in foreign key referencing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at the changes in data type of Airline_ID and Source_Airport_ID: Data type should be same as source table of the foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE `routes1` (
`Airline` varchar(3) default NULL,
`Airline_ID` int(5) default NULL,
`Source_Airport` varchar(4) default NULL,
`Source_Airport_ID` int(5) default NULL,
`Destination_Airport` varchar(4) default NULL,
`Destination_Airport_ID` varchar(4) default NULL,
`CodeShare` char(1),
`Stops` int(1),
`Equipment` text,
 FOREIGN KEY(Airline_ID) REFERENCES airlines(Airline_ID)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(Source_Airport_ID) REFERENCES airports(Airport_ID)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

If the answer is correct please mark as an answer. Thank you.

For more information you can see the following link:

> [Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238321/supports-transactions-row-level-locking-and-foreign-keys)